# SpriteKit Particle Emitter Not Appearing in Xcode Editor

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode6

I'm having a constant issue of particle effects not appearing in the editor.  Everything works fine when I first create them, but after some time they stop appearing. I just see the black background, but the particles aren't there.

The only way I'm able to deal with this problem is to delete the node and create a new particle node with the same attributes, which is time consuming and annoying.  And then, after a while, the same thing happens to the new particle nodes.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: There is a known issue about particle editor in Xcode 6.0.1 What is your Xcode version ? Xcode 6.1 should work fine. If that's not an issue, you can print screen and update a post with configuration for problematic emitter.

Comment: i have this problem with emitters that make short burts of particles.  something like an explosion.  when I look at them in the editor the explosion will only happen one time.  it wont repeat. otherwise i dont have this issue

Comment: @hamobi  set the maximum particles to 0.

Comment: I'm having the problem that the particles *never* appear in the particle editor (can reproduce with a blank project), Xcode 7.1.1. Workarounds described by @ron-myschuk does not work

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me all of time after editing a value and switching to code view of another page. Come back and the preview is gone. Can confirm it is still broken in Xcode 7.3 Beta

There are a couple of home remedies that work until it gets fixed by Apple.

Right click on the file --> Open As --> Quick Look
   select a different file and come back and it should work now

or

Close the emitter document with File --> Close “Particle.sks” (Control-Command-W) and reopening it should circumvent the issue.

Hope this helps in the mean time