# Particle Emitter not acting consistently

Tags: xcode6, skemitternode

I'm using the same particle emitter in multiple scenes, and I'm noticing that in some scenes when I run the app on a phone that the emitter isn't appearing when its supposed to. It then changes to a different scene next time I open the app so it's really inconsistent. I thought about creating a different emitter for each scene but that seems to be pointless if 1 emitter can be used across scenes. I saw this question that was related:

[SpriteKit Particle Emitter Not Appearing in Xcode Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141300/spritekit-particle-emitter-not-appearing-in-xcode-editor)

But no answers, just wondering if anyone else has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem sourced to the z position of the emitter node, it was set to equal to the background which I can only assume that this caused it to act strangely as when I set the z position higher it stopped.